# How to upload an image to server?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, file-io

I am building project with spring boot and i want to upload image to server (on my local server).

Code for uploading file is :

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
public class ImageController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/upload", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody String provideUploadInfo() {
        return "You can upload a file by posting to this same URL.";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/upload", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("name") String name,@RequestParam("email") String email,
            @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file){
        if (!file.isEmpty()) {
             BufferedImage src;
            try {
                src = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(file.getBytes()));
             File destination = new File("/"+System.getProperty("user.home")+"/samepinchbucket/"+email+"/pics/"); 
                 ImageIO.write(src, "png", destination);
             //Save the id you have used to create the file name in the DB. You can retrieve the image in future with the ID.
             return "You successfully uploaded " + name + "!";
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "You failed to upload " + name + " => " + e.getMessage();
            }
             }else{
                 return "You failed to upload " + name + " because the file was empty.";
             }
    }

}
```

This code is working fine but image is being uploaded in `myfolder` with `pics` as name of image but my requirment is that image should be uploaded inside `pics` folder not in `email folder`.

Answer (score 1):

You should simply use a different [`File`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) constructor, e.g.

```
String folder = "/"+System.getProperty("user.home")+ "/samepinchbucket/"+email+"/pics/";
File destination = new File(folder, file.getOriginalFilename());
```

this will store the files inside a folder `pics` under the original filename

Answer (score 0):

From your code, it seems you are using some Java web server with Spring.

Suppose the `getImageDirPath()` method returns the `imagePath` relative to tomcat server home directory:

```java
  private static String getImageDirPath(String email) {
    String envVal = null;
    String rootPath = System.getProperty("catalina.home");
    File dir = new File(rootPath + File.separator + "samepinchbucket" + File.separator + 
                        email+File.separator + "pics" + File.separator);
    if (!dir.exists())
        dir.mkdirs();
    return dir.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator;
}
```

Reference: http://www.proactiveclass.com/tutorials/java/spring/image-upload-android-app-using-spring-tomcat-server